# JavaScript Module not incrementing number correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to learn how to write modules in JavaScript.  With this attempt I am trying to load 10 pictures from Flickr on page load, and then load 10 more pictures once the user scrolls to the bottom of the page.  This is not firing consistantly and I am not sure why.

I would like to load 10 pictures at page load, and then 10 additional pictures each time the user scrolls down to the bottom of the page.

I think the issue is with the `curPage` property that is called using `this.settings.curPage`

curPage is incremented in the `jaxPhotos` method using `this.settings.curPage++`

I am not sure but I think the issue is with either the `jaxPhotos` method or the `scrollMorePics` method.

Here's a fiddle with my module:http://jsfiddle.net/R3Bt7/

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="flickrContainer" data-options='{"searchQuery" : "candy", "tagQuery" : "candy", "tagMode": "all", "picsPerPage" : "10", "curPage" : 1}'>

</div>
```

Here's my JS:

```
var FlickrModule = (function ($element) {

  var flickrFeed = function () {
    this.$element = $element;

    this.init();
  };

  flickrFeed.prototype.init = function () {
    this.setOptions()
        .jaxPhotos(this.settings.curPage)
        .onScrollHandler();
  };

  flickrFeed.prototype.setOptions = function () {
    var options = this.$element.data().options;

    var defaults = {
        searchQuery : '',
        tagQuery : '',
        tagMode : '',
        picsPerPage: '1',
        curPage: 1
    }

    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    return this;
  };

  flickrFeed.prototype.jaxPhotos = function (pageNumber) {
    var self = this;

    // ajax call to flickr json
    $.ajax({
        url: '//api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&tags=' + this.settings.searchQuery + '&tag_mode=' + this.settings.tagMode + '&page=' + this.settings.currPage + '&per_page=' + this.settings.picsPerPage + '&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: JSON,
        success: function (data) {

            // start assembling some dom elements to wrap around each page
            var pageTxtWrap = document.createElement('div'),
            pageTxt= document.createElement('p');

            pageTxt.textContent = 'Page ' + pageNumber + ' - Scroll down for more pictures!';
            pageTxt.innerText = 'Page ' + pageNumber + ' - Scroll down for more pictures!';

            pageTxtWrap.className = 'pageTextWrap';

            pageTxtWrap.appendChild(pageTxt);

            // Use createDocumentFragment() as it is the fastest method of element creation
            var docFragPageHdr = document.createDocumentFragment();
            docFragPageHdr.appendChild(pageTxtWrap);
            document.body.appendChild(docFragPageHdr);

            // create variables for easier access to the JSON trees we're using
            flickr = data.photos,
            flickrLength = flickr.photo.length;

            // run through the JSON we just got and assemble the pictures
            for (var i = 0; i < flickrLength; i++) {
                var farmId = flickr.photo[i].farm,
                serverId = flickr.photo[i].server,
                photoId = flickr.photo[i].id,
                secretId = flickr.photo[i].secret,
                imgTitle = flickr.photo[i].title;

                var flickImg = document.createElement('img');

                flickImg.className = 'flickerImg';
                flickImg.id = 'flickImg'+i;
                flickImg.title = imgTitle;
                flickImg.src = 'http://farm' + farmId + '.staticflickr.com/' + serverId + '/' + photoId + '_' + secretId + '_m.jpg';

                var docFragFlickImg = document.createDocumentFragment();
                docFragFlickImg.appendChild(flickImg);
                document.body.appendChild(docFragFlickImg);
            }
        }
    });

    // increase currPage so we can go to the next page of pictures
    this.settings.curPage++;

    return this;
  };

  flickrFeed.prototype.onScrollHandler = function () {
    $(document).on('scroll', this.scrollMorePics.bind(this));

    return this;
  };

  flickrFeed.prototype.scrollMorePics = function(){
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50 ) { 
        console.log('Before ajax curPage = ', this.settings.curPage);
        this.jaxPhotos(this.settings.curPage);
        console.log('After ajax curPage = ', this.settings.curPage);
    };

    return this;
  };

  return flickrFeed;

}( $('.flickrContainer') ));

(function () {
  var myModule = new FlickrModule();
})();
```

Comment: Why are you returning `this` in your prototype functions? `$element` should be passed as an argument to the constructor function (since you're attaching it as an instance variable, I assume you want it to be unique for each instance).

Comment: I'm actually still trying to figure out `this`.  `this` should be a reference to the flickrFeed object, I think and I thought I should return that.

Comment: In this case there is no point of doing that. Are you planning to create more than one instance? Otherwise I would return an object rather than a constructor function

Comment: I'd like to be able to return more than 1 instance.  It probably doesn't make sense in this case with the point being to load more pictures once the page has been scrolled.  But I'd like to make a module that can be used for more than 1 instance.

Comment: If you want `this` to be available in every prototype extension as a reference to flickrFeed, you can extend flickrFeed using a prototype object instead of individual extensions, which may actually make things easier to read. Just use `flickrFeed.prototype = { jaxPhotos : function() { ... }, setOptions : function() { ... }, etc...` Also, if you're extending a function object with prototype, you don't need to return `this` in each function, as it will be available to all extension functions.

Comment: @Lazerblade The downside of an object would be that he can't inherit from another prototype, since it would be overwritten.

Comment: @Johan true, but if done right, only a single instance of the object would be needed, making the code smaller and faster, since it would be contained in a single tree.

Comment: @Lazerblade If only one instance is needed, I would say instances isn't the way to go in the first place. Returning an object rather than a function would be more suitable in that case, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

A small example on how you can access instance variables and methods based on your code:

```
var FlickrModule = (function ($) {

    var flickrFeed = function ($element) {

        this.$element = $element;
        this.init();
    };

    flickrFeed.prototype.init = function(){
        console.log('init', this.$element);
    };

    return flickrFeed;

})(jQuery);

$(function(){

    var $container = $('.flickrContainer'),
        fm = new FlickrModule($container);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5nJqM/

Comment: Thank you.  I've updated my fiddle to pass the jQuery object to $element as you've demonstrated.  I find when I remove the `return this` pieces though that it fails.  I'll look into what's going on there, I know the module is pretty huge now.  I was trying to break out different opertaions into different methods.

Comment: @Mdd I just wanted to give you a basic example here. Let me know if you have any questions